# COPY not working with docker-compose but works find with docker build

Tags: angular, nginx, docker-compose

I am tasked with dockerizing an angular app and serve it with Nginx.

I have built the angular project to a dist folder and want to move this folder to nginx->html directory in the built container along with other different microservices.

This is how my docker project is structured

```
 |-dist/
 |-Dockerfile
 |-dockerignore
 |-default.config
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

#Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

On top of this directory is a bunch of other services that need to run alongside the angular app which is all running as expected. With the following docker-compose.yml file

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  adminportal:
    build: ./adminPortal
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "/usr/share/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html"
      - "/etc/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
```

When I build this container with docker build and run it runs as expected "copying dist content to the right folder and copying the config to the right dir".
But if build with `docker-compose up --build`, everything runs fine returning no error but it does not copy the files to their respective nginx folders.

Comment: Do you have folders "/usr/share/nginx/html", "/etc/nginx/conf.d" to volume map  ?

Comment: yes i do have the folder

Comment: Isn't docker-compose building the image using the same dockerfile

Comment: Yes it is, but it is not copying the dist content to the desired location

Comment: I did have similar setup. It is working perfectly fine for me. Can you verify are you using the correct dockerfile by adding "RUN echo "Hello"" in your dockerfile to make sure it is picking up correct dockerfile in both the scenarios.

Comment: there was a typo in the volumes address, you mentioning folders in the first comment helped me focus on the volumes and solved it thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, I solved passing the `--build` parameter to the `docker-compose` command, like below:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

In this way you are forcing docker-compose to build your image. In my case, the `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```